# how open phonepe or google pay using upi deeplinking in ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift4

Im trying to integrate UPI payment in my app. i have seen some apps where they are providing google pay and phone pe buttons, if they are installed in the device. on clicking button, particular app is opening.
I need to implement similar experience in my ios app.

i have tried generating URL as specified in NPCI doc https://www.npci.org.in/sites/all/themes/npcl/images/PDF/UPI_Linking_Specs_ver_1.5.1.pdf

i tried using   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler  to open the UPI app. every time its opening whatsapp only.

How can we open phone pe / google pay app based on users selection without entering payer's UPI id.

Comment: Here is updated NPCI doc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803273/how-open-phonepe-or-google-pay-using-upi-deeplinking-in-ios-using-swift

Answer (score 1):

It is opening WhatsApp because Generic Intent does not work on iOS.

For Gpay you could try below codes:

```
@IBAction func Gpay(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: "tez://upi/pay?pa=test@dcb&cu=INR&mc=0000&appName=TEST&tn=To&am=1.0&pn=TEST&tr=TEST-1574159602900") else {
        return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get deeplink url of PhonePe as below

`PhonePeSDK.shared().deeplinkUrl`

Comment: thank you for your quick response. If need to integrate google pay, then i need use google pay sdk also?

Comment: @sanjayk please share the procedure how to integrate Google pay. I am looking for solution I didn't find proper documents.. thank you

Comment: Is anyone find any solution to how to integrate Google Pay in iOS?